# Is there a way to automatically set OSX /etc/hosts file with VMWare Fusion?

Tags: networking, vmware-fusion

I use VMWare Fusion all the time for development, and one of the most common things I need to do is set my /etc/hosts file to have a special hostname resolve to it. It'd be great if there were a way that whenever my VM boots up, something is able to update my hosts file automatically with a hosts entry to the Virtual machine's IP address that is assigned (Bridged networking)

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Why not just set the VM to use a static IP address instead?

Comment: @techie007 the only way I could do that would be to use NAT routing, and at my workplace setting a public static IP wouldn't be an option.